# Is it possible to use Facebook OG tag in an <img> tag in the body of a page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In a WordPress site I'm building, I'd ideally like to make the first post image the og:image for that page. I don't yet know what that image is when the header is called, however.

Is there a way to specify the og:image within the `<img>` tag itself, or somewhere else in the `<body>`?

Comment: No. You will have to figure it out and put it in the head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the protocol, you can't. When calling the header you should have access to the current loop or post object though. When writing your theme I suggest you use a function to determine the image or use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this one is, apparently, NO.